# Primefaces treeNode edit/update issue :unable to type in inputText

Tags: jsf, primefaces, tree, treenode

I have a `tree` with nodes,which i want to update. But when i click on the input box, it's not focused and i can't type anything.
If I click my mouse inside the box and keep my finger pressed on it, then i can type.

```
<p:tree value="#{createTestBean.root}" var="node" id="tree" >  
       <p:treeNode id="treeNode"> 
      <h:outputText value="#{node.operationName}"/>
      <h:inputText value="#{node.opValue}" />  
   </p:treeNode>  
 </p:tree>
```

Comment: Same problem for me, that's weird.

Comment: try use 'p:treeTable' or select a node and edit in a differente component outside of 'p:tree'; ex.: '<p:tree > stuffs, ajaxnodeselect'</p:tree> <p:inputText value="#{yourbean.yourselectednode.data.youreditproperty}"/> hope's help you (maybe late);